# Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the equation has finite number of solutions

Tags: real-analysis

The motivation to this question can be found in: [Can we deduce that the equation $f(x)=0$ has finite number of solutions in the interval $(-∞,2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474504/can-we-deduce-that-the-equation-fx-0-has-finite-number-of-solutions-in-the-i)

My question is: Assume that $f$ is not a polynomial, then: Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the equation has finite number of solutions in the interval $(−∞,2)$.

Comment: If f is a polynomial of degree n, then f can have at most n zeros in the real line. If f is monotonic, non-zero, then it will have at most one solution. But you can have infinitely-many with, e.g., $sin(1/x)$

Comment: @DBF: I assume that $f$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: then being monotonic is sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: If its derivative (or 2nd derivative, or third derivative, ...) has only finitely many zeros in the interval, then $f$ has only finitely many. I think the only necessary and sufficient condition is that the equation should have only finitely many solutions in the interval.